# Horizontal Line (NSBox) Remove backshadow - Swift

Tags: swift, border, layer, nsbox

So i have this app and it uses visual effect view to make the container of the app, in this app i have a line separator using an NSBox and when i run it it comes up with this [image]

you can see it comes up but has kinda like a 1 or 2 pixel outlines around it? How do i get rid of this

Comment: Post code of what you've tried.

Comment: I'm unclear as to what the desired behavior is. You want that line to the right of **Days** to be invisible? I thought you wanted that line as a separator?

Comment: i want the line to be there, but as you can see it has this weird glow around it that it shouldnt have. Like 1 or 2 pixels around it, the other ones dont have this weird glow

Answer (score 0):

Make the border type of NSBox to "None" or make the border width to zero through interface builder.